# JavaScript object call one method from another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following object literal how do I call `c` from within `b`?

**Update 1 - missed one thing I use JQuery load, which changes the context:**

```
var a = {
    b: function (e) {

        $o.load(path, function (e) { // need to call c from here });
    },
    c: function (e) { 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do `a.c()` inside `.b`:

```
var a = {
    b: function(e) {
        a.c();
    },
    c: function(e) {}
};

a.b(); // calls c
```

Also, `this` will be bound to the `a` object which will allow you to access its properties using `this.property`:

```
b: function(e) {
    this.c();
},
```

Comment: Sorry mate I missed one detail - I use JQuery load call, so I need to proxy the loaded event handler somehow...

Comment: note that `this === a` is only a sure thing if you call `a.b()` -_directly_. Assign the `b` function to another obj, or use it as a jQuery event handler, and `this` will change.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = {
    b: function (e) {
        a.c();
    },

    c: function (e) {
        // magic goes here
    }
};
```

`a` will be a closure so it's accessible in the functions (that is, `a` is defined in an wide, outer scope, which the narrower, inner scopes in each function inherit). Calling context is irrelevant; closures are formed when and where the functions are defined, so inside `b`, object `a` will always stay the same (unlike `this`, which can change).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

```
var a = {
b: function(e) {
    a.c();
},
c: function(e) {}
};

a.b();
```

Answer (score 2):

From the method `b` you may call `c` using `this.c` as long as they are on the same object. However for the function expression being passed to `$o` I would suggest you `bind` the `this` pointer of `b` to it. Thus you do:

```
var a = {
    b: function (e) {
        $o.load(path, function (e) {
            this.c();
        }.bind(this));
    },
    c: function (e) {
    }
};
```

**Edit:** The way you're creating and using this object is fragile. The `this` pointer may point to anything, such as when you unbind the methods or call it with a different context. Even using `a.c` isn't foolproof as other code may change `a` and when the method `b` is called `a` will point to something else.

I would do something like this:

```
var a = function (a) {
    a.b = function (e) {
        $o.load(path, function (e) {
            a.c();
        });
    };

    a.c = function (e) {
    };

    return a;
}({});
```

This code can not be tampered with and allows you to create private variables and closures.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something but bind() doesn't change this of my loaded handler. I tried passing in a few different things including just a string but my this is always a html object.

Comment: Perhaps you could show me your actual code. It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3bkzD/

Comment: I've found something more elegant than your solution being $,proxy. see my answer.

Comment: JQuery `proxy` was used before browsers started natively supporting `bind`. I wouldn't prefer it over `bind` for any purpose. Native `bind` is [approximately 90% faster](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/2 "bind vs jQuery.proxy · jsPerf") than `jquery.proxy`.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution which requires the minimum changes is to use `jQuery.proxy()`:

```
var a = {
    b: function (e) {

        $o.load(path, $.proxy(function (e) { this.c(); }, this));
    },
    c: function (e) { 
    }
};
```

Comment: `$.proxy` is similar to my method of using `bind`. In fact I would say that my method is better: http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy/2

Comment: Note however that this method still suffers from the same problem my method does. If the `this` pointer is changed (either by unbinding the methods or by changing the context using `call` or `apply`) then `this` will not point to the correct object. It's better to use my second method in this case.